# Where to insert an internal (utility) object with a compatible RequireJS/AMD JavaScript library

Tags: javascript

Maybe the title is not quite useful to understand what is the problem but I'll try to explain in a clear way what I would achieve.

Following **Jeremy Kahn** template (you can found it at [GitHub](https://github.com/jeremyckahn/lib-tmpl/blob/master/dist/library.js)) I'm creating a library that is compatible with RequireJS and AMD.

The library looks like the following (skipped code for brevity).

```
;(function(global, undefined) {

    var Fn = Function, GLOBAL = new Fn('return this')();

    function initLSKitCore(context, _) {

        'use strict';

        // private vars here...

        var LSKit = context.LSKit = function(options) {

            this.groups = [];

            return this;
        };

        /**
         * Add a new Group
         */
        LSKit.prototype.addGroup = function(groupId) {

            // implementation here...
        };

        // other prototype methods...
    }

    var initLSKit = function(context, deps) {

        var context = deps ? {} : global;

        var _ = (deps && deps.underscore) ? deps.underscore : context._;

        initLSKitCore(context, _);

        // other modules here...

        return context.LSKit;
    };

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

        define(["underscore"], function (Underscore) {

            var underscoreSupportsAMD = (Underscore != null);

            // Some versions of Underscore.js support AMD, others don't.
            // If not, use the `_` global.
            var deps = { underscore: underscoreSupportsAMD ? Underscore : _ };
            var SLKit = initLSKit({}, deps);
            return SLKit;
        });
    } else {
        initLSKit(this);
    }

}(this));
```

The `groups` array enables to store, retrieve or get `Group` objects defined like this.

```
function Group(identifier, name){
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.name = name;
    this.internalList = [];
};
```

Based on that my actual requirement is the following. I would like to use `Group` as an internal class (I know the term is not correct since it's actually an internal object). So, where is the right place to insert the second snippet (i.e. `Group` constructor) in my library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your template, you'd just need to inject it in the `initLSkit` method

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(["underscore", "lib/group"], function (Underscore, Group) {

        var underscoreSupportsAMD = (Underscore != null);

        // Some versions of Underscore.js support AMD, others don't.
        // If not, use the `_` global.
        var deps = { underscore: underscoreSupportsAMD ? Underscore : _, Group: Group };
        var SLKit = initLSKit({}, deps);
        return SLKit;
    });
} else {
    initLSKit(this, { Group: global.Group });
}
```

I believe it is always better to inject your dependencies. So I'd inject underscore too when using the global context. Adding dependency resolution logic inside the `initLSKit` is just noise inside your business logic (Concerns separation FTW).

Without AMD loading, you can also declare it locally to your module like this:

```
;(function(global, undefined) {

    var Fn = Function, GLOBAL = new Fn('return this')();

    // Just create it here, it'll be available inside your module
    // and won't be reachable from outside the module (private).
    var Group = function() {};

// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In this case I would like to use it as an internal class. Is it possible?

Comment: What would be the best approach?

Comment: Then simply declare it inside the closure, it'll be only available locally.

Comment: Is this a good design approach? What if `Group` will have `prototype` methods? +1 for your support. P.S. An example could be useful. Maybe just indicate where it should go...

Comment: Well, it depends... If your library will be big, then I'd suggest you build it 100% with AMD (or commonjs) and then make a build script to combine the library into a single file with a single export value (so you'd hide the internal classes). But this is a completly different subject. If you want to investigate this further, you can take jQuery as example. It is build 100% with AMD internally, but it is build for distribution into a single file without an AMD loader dependency.

Comment: Added local example in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. For now I will follow this approach. Maybe I'll try to find something better since I don't like to have there prototypes for `Group`.